# Example of a semigroup such that it contains a sub-semigroup which is a non-trivial group

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

> Give an example of a semi-group such that it contains a sub-semigroup
>   which is a non-trivial group.

I am not very sure what a sub-semigroup is but according to Wikipedia:

The semigroup operation induces an operation on the collection of its subsets: given subsets $A$ and $B$ of a semigroup $S$, their product $A·B$, written commonly as $AB$, is the set $\{ ab | a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \}$. (This notion is defined identically as it is for groups.)

In terms of this operation, a subset $A$ is called a subsemigroup if $AA$ is a subset of $A$.

That is they mean $A$ will be a subsemigroup iff $\{a^2|a\in A\}$ is a subset of the set $\{a|a\in A\}$.

I was thinking that since $(\Bbb Z^{+},+)$ is a semigroup, it's subsemigroup $\{1^2,2^2,3^2,...\}$ could be a valid semi-semigroup could be a valid answer. *But* the problem is that it does not satisfy "closure". Say $2^2+5^2$ isn't an element of $\{1^2,2^2,3^2,...\}$. Any other possible answers to the question?

Comment: Your sentence that starts "That is..." is not correct. You need all possible products, not just the squares. Anyway, it just means that the subset is closed under the multiplication in the semigroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, $\{a^2|a\in A\}$ has to be a subset of $A$ first of all (to qualify as a sub-semigroup). Then to be a semigroup it requires closure. So yeah...

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about is whether a sub-semigroup is a group or whether it is a semi-group

Comment: The condition written on wikipedia is precisely that it is closed under the multiplication. A subsemigroup is a semigroup, but not necessarily a group. Your task is to find an example where it really is a (non-trivial) group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the clarification. I have been trying to find an example but no luck so far.

Comment: Hint for a "silly" solution: A group is also a semigroup.

Comment: A couple of hints, going in different directions.

Given a set $A$ with at least two elements, consider the semigroup of maps on $A$ under map composition.

Given a group $G$, consider adding an element to obtain a semigroup that is not a group (the latter condition being possibly implicit in the question).

Answer (score 1):

> As a quick recap to be on the same page:
>
> 1. A *subsemigroup* of a semigroup $G$ is a subset $S$ which is closed under the multiplication **induced from $G$**.
>
> This implies that your subsemigroup $(S,\cdot_{|G})$ is also a semigroup in its own right.
>
> 2. A *subgroup* of a semigroup $G$ is a subsemigroup which happens to be a group.

As for your question, you can construct many example by hand.

But if you want an example quite natural, but not trivial, I'd suggest going for $(\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R}), \cdot)$ the 2x2-matrix semigroup (over $\mathbb{R}$) with matrix multiplication.

Aside from the trivial subgroup $\{\mathbf{0}\}$, you should be able to find another one which is quite famous (hint: it contains the identity matrix $\mathbf{1}$).

Furthermore, interestingly enough, $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ contains also an infinite family of subgroups which aren't trivial (and they aren't that hard to describe as a set once you've found them).

Answer (score 1):

Any nontrivial group is a semigroup and hence a solution to your question.
If you want a group $G$ which is different from the original semigroup, take $S = G \cup \{0\}$, where $0$ is a new element and define the product by $0$ by setting, for all $s \in S$, $s0= 0s = 0$.